# Error opening registry key ‘Software\JavaSoft\JRE’ while installing elki

Tags: java, elki

I am trying to download ELKI. So as per the readme file I run the elki.bat( I am using windows 10 ). But I get the following java related errors :

> Error: opening registry key ‘Software\JavaSoft\JRE’
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

- I have searched all the sources that address this problem.
- I uninstalled the previous version and reinstalled JDK ( I currently have jdk 11.0.1 installed ). The "java -version" command to check the version runs just fine.
- I have set the java path and classpath.

The README file says that the jar files from the elki and dependency folder must be included in the path. I've done that as well, but the error persists.

Please help!

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading Java 10 to 11, but did not dare to delete the files, because "javapath" is just a link to "javapath_target_2695656". So I renamed it "old_java..." and the command "java -version" worked. Now I have other problems, which I will analyze first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELKI doesn't know what the Windows registry is.

The error supposedly originates from Java - so there is something broken in your Windows Java installation. Others have reported the same error when running `java -version`. I'd expect other Java programs to be affected, too: if you search for the error message, you will mostly find it with other software, e.g., here: [Install Java 11 OpenJDK on Windows (a system path issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690937/install-java-11-openjdk-on-windows-a-system-path-issue)

I suggest that you (1) uninstall all Java versions, (2) run "java -version" to make sure you really removed all, (3) reboot, Windows needs this to reset some system variables, (4) reinstall the Java version(s) you intend to use (5) reboot once more, in case Java installation changed the system variables once more. If that worked, please report so.

Nevertheless, the ELKI 0.7.1 release **will *not* work with Java 11**. You will need to **compile the latest version from Github**, because of subtle incompatibilities in Java. These are already fixed in ELKI (removing a cast that no longer worked, but also was not necessary), there just has not been a new release yet, sorry. It is developer software, users are expected to use the source. Right now, ELKI is only well tested with Java 8, because of the module mess introduced in Java 9, and not all dependencies being ported to the module system yet.

Comment: It worked with Java 8! Thank you! I am completely new to data mining and am working on my 1st project...The elki tutorials look a little confusing.. could you please suggest some tutorials that could help beginners?

Comment: I need to perform cluster analysis for the project

Comment: It is a developer and research software. You probably are looking for something with commercial support such as Rapidminer or KNIME.

Comment: Oh no! I am a student and am working on my 1st ML project...I was suggested ELKI by my teacher. I'll try learning it...Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**java 11 error: opening registry key 'software\javasoft\java runtime environment'**

I started a training program on LinkedIn on 2/5/19. It required me to install the new Java JDK 11.0.2 version. After installing the new Java JDK 11 it wasn’t showing up in MS DOS. When I typed in java version it would show the old java 10 version. I fixed that problem by removing all old versions.

(1) uninstall all Java versions, (2) run "java -version" to make sure you really removed all, (3) reboot, Windows needs this to reset some system variables, (4) reinstall the Java version(s) you intend to use (5) reboot once more, in case Java installation changed the system variables once more.

Thanks:[Error opening registry key ‘Software\JavaSoft\JRE’ while installing elki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007069/error-opening-registry-key-software-javasoft-jre-while-installing-elki)

However, a new problem started. I received an error message:

Error:  opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'

Error:  could not find java.dll

Error:  Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

I checked my path in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\

Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment Variables

Set PATH and JAVA HOME with: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin

Edit System Variable

New

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\;……

**remove all others**

Still was having the problem until I did this:

**FIXED ISSUE:**

Windows > Start > cmd >

I used this first one:

```
C:> for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

or
    C:> where java

It return 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath' folder which contain:

MUST REMOVE:

```
java.exe
javaw.exe
javaws.exe
```

Browse to this folder with Windows file explorer and remove everything (three files above).

Close and reopen cmd (Windows > Start > cmd >)

```
C:> java -version
```

Should now return:

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15

OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

or something similar depending on which java release package you've downloaded...

It works!

https://superuser.com/questions/1382158/on-windows-why-java-version-return-error-opening-registry-key-software-javas

Thank you to these guys that help me with this issue!! Wanted to share this with others so they wouldn't spend hours trying to fix this issue!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and welcome to StackOverflow :) May I suggest you to be a little bit more concise, to keep your answer clear and readable by other users. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Zandseam - Thanks for an easy answer!